# LNK2019 error while creating an object in another solution c++

Tags: c++, linker-errors, lnk2019

I'm trying to create objects by using another c++ solution's files.

- When I create a `MyClass1` object program gives error of:

  ```
  1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall MyClass1::~MyClass1(void)" (??1MyClass1@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
  1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall MyClass1::MyClass1(class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (??0MyClass1@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z) referenced in function _main
  ```
- When I create a `MyClass2` object program creates the object. No error.

What should I do to create the `MyClass1` object properly?

---

I cut all unnecessary parts in relevant source. The code is as follows.

tester file **main.cpp**

```
#include "tester.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

#include "myclasses.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    tester w;
    w.show();

    MyClass1 aa;
    MyClass2 bbb;

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

**myclasses.h** file

```
#ifndef MYCLASSES_H
#define MYCLASSES_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_myclasses.h"

class MyClass1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass1(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~MyClass1();

    void setthemall(int number);

private:
    Ui::MyClass1Class ui;
    int totalnumber;
};

class MyClass2 
{
    int param1;
    void getit ();
};


#endif
```

---

**myclasses.cpp** file

```
#include "myclasses.h"

MyClass1::MyClass1(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
: QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

MyClass1::~MyClass1()
{
}

void MyClass1::setthemall(int pnumber)
{
    totalnumber=pnumber;
}


void MyClass2::getit() {

};
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the myclasses.o file is missing. Are you sure you're compiling and linking myclasses.o?

Since this is Qt, have you run "qmake -project" after you added this source file to your project?

Comment: > i built the solution which includes "myclasses.cpp" and "myclasses.h" in Visual Studio.  > Then i added the location of "myclasses.h" to the Project Properties' Additional Include Directories. > But i didn't add the myclasses.obj file to the new solution. Should i put it in the Properties of Linker?

Comment: I haven't compiled anything that uses Qt under Visual Studio. However, by the errors you mention, it seems like every symbol you define in myclasses.cpp is not being linked. Qt requires you to run "qmake" to generate makefiles, and to generate the "moc"s that this library uses to add the slot and signal functionality to the classes you define, which inherit from QObject. You can't bypass this, since Qt relies on the "moc"s to make everythin work OK. I don't know if you have to manually add the object file to the solution, but you could try so :D